# Java download and upload files to Google Drive

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am using Eclipse on Windows 10. I am coding a simple java app to list contents in a local/remote directory and open/download/upload whichever is selected. The challenge is that while I could do this for all the drives on my computer and on my network using their address, I don't know how to go about reading from directories on my google drive.
I understand that there is an API but it all seems to be so complicated in usage. Is there an easy way to just access the drive like this:

```
public class GDriveInterface {
String driveDrirectory= "C:/";
File listDir = new File(driveDrirectory);
public GDriveInterface() {
    if(listDir.exists()){
        String[] dirlist = listDir.list();
        for (String out:dirlist){
            System.out.println(out);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GDriveInterface();
}
```

}

If I can get it easily as in the code above I could probably easily download/copy/upload to that directory. Any straightforward ideas?

Comment: As you correctly pointed out there is an API. It is well documented. Read the documentation and use the API. That's why it exists. If it is "too complicated" to use you should probably take a few steps back and do a couple simpler projects. It's not a good idea to jump in a copy/paste-project when you are learning to code as you will look back at it and have no idea what the code does.

Comment: Also to answer your question: No there is not... else why would they provide an api with things like... authentication and security?

Comment: The challenge I am facing in the quickstart is preparing the project, where gradle is required. I am using Eclipse, and JDK, not SDK. This quickstart seems to assume that you are using Android Studio or the like to do the programming. I don't know if I am wrong...